# How do ceramic thermistors work?

Tags: electrical-resistance, semiconductor-physics

I can hardly find any information..  and the few I got from my script is not revealing so much:

> Electrons are strongly bounded (ceramics) – electrons are transported from a bound state into an energetically similar vicinal state by thermal activation (hole transport).

[image]

Is it just that? For me, this could also be applied to a semiconductor resistor.

Comment: There should be an image but I can't see but it might be my browser atm. Could you please tell wether you're able to see that?

Comment: I see an image - Red dots in Cyan -> more spread out, Blue dots in white.

Comment: Alright, thank you ;)

Answer (score 2):

Ceramic resistors are not generally dependant on mechanisms shown in your diagram. There are several processes which produce what might be called "ceramic resistors" but the most usual are "CERMET" (ceramic-metal) resistors consisting of a sintered electrically non-conductive material with distributed conductive metal particles. The metal provides a large number of interlinked multiple paths through the material resulting in a strong, high temperature non inductive resistor.

From [here](https://www.explainthatstuff.com/cermets.html) - cermets.

[image]

- Here's the structure of a typical cermet made from particles of ceramic alumina (red), each of which is surrounded by platinum metal (blue). Although electricity doesn't normally flow through a ceramic, it can flow through a cermet (yellow arrowed line) by following a circuit through the platinum. Artwork based on a drawing from US Patent 4,183,746: Cermets by Stephen L. Pearce and Gordon L. Selman, Johnson, Matthey & Co., Limited, courtesy of US Patent and Trademark Office.

Some characteristics [ceramic resistors] from "US Resistor" (http://www.usresistor.com/index.php/materials/ceramic-resistors)

- Ceramic resistors are manufactured from a sintered body of ceramic material, with conductive particles distributed throughout the matrix, to produce a resistor that is 100% active and non-inductive.  Ceramic resistors are chemically inert.  They can withstand high-energy and high-voltages at high temperatures, such as those encountered in the protection of high voltage surge equipment, discharge banks, and in high frequency radiation suppression.  Electrical characteristics are as follows:

[Patent US4183746](https://patents.google.com/patent/US4183746) cermets - a number of the citations are very relevant.

See also patent [High-temperature-resistant cermet material and preparation method thereof](https://patents.google.com/patent/CN104388792A/en)

Comment: Thanks a lot but I lack a bit of physical content to understand it. E.g. ceramics are mostly build as NTCs. Why is that? I know it wasn't part of my question but I thought it would be in the answer :)

Comment: @Ben 1. Please ensure that we are talking about the same materials. 2. Either add to this question or perhaps start a new one. 3. Se Electrical Engineering MIGHT be better for this - maybe not.

Comment: I'm interested in the physics behind it and - apparently - ceramic resistors are mainly used as NTCs, so for me this is quite connected to each other.

Comment: @Ben Ceramic resistor's main uses would almost certainly NOT be NTC - can you cite a link or few? I'd expect that if you used eg Platinum (as per some examples) as the infill metal that you'd get a PTC. You could build them with Nichrome or Chromel (I imagine) for close to 0 TC. || Ohmite make a wide range of ceramic resistors - Here are some of their [high power range](https://www.ohmite.com/catalog?cid=root&filter=category%3A2%3A800%20Series%20Ceramic&cdskeys=ceramic#cds-attribute-category) | Note selector boxes on left side - check as required.

Comment: Odds are your confusion is due to 'incorrect' terminology. You perhaps mean "thermistor" - indeed mainly NTCs. see [here](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&sxsrf=ALeKk00Jy_0aZPr5BpPm0l5mKMCGABP0KA%3A1594815003967&ei=G_IOX_nPOtGX4-EPm6mHUA&q=ceramic+thermistor+ntc&oq=ceramic+thermistor+ntc&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIGCAAQCBAeOgQIABBHOgQIABANOggIABAIEAcQHjoICAAQCBANEB5Q_HxYqo8BYPSbAWgAcAF4AIAB0wGIAbkPkgEGMC4xMC4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwi5yazunM_qAhXRyzgGHZvUAQoQ4dUDCAw&uact=5)

Comment: Much about NTC thermistors [here](https://www.te.com/global-en/products/sensors/temperature-sensors/ntc-thermistors-sensors/advances-in-ntc-ceramic-technology.html)

Comment: ah, oh, ok sorry, I thought that is the same but yes, it is about thermistors! I will change it! Thanks!